# Bison parser always prints syntax error without specifying what is wrong

Tags: gcc, gnu, bison, flex-lexer

Hi everyone I'm trying to write a parser for this simple java simple file basically I want this parser to recognise and validate instuction blocks. Upon finding a correct instruction block, the validator would print a success message.

Input file:

```
{ 
  a = b; 
}

{
  counter = counter- 1;
  i = i + 1;
}

{
  variable1 = i / j;
  variable2 = i * j;
  i++;
  j--;

}
```

but no matter what I tried I always get syntax error

Bison **parser.y code**:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%union {
char * str;
}
%token IDENTIFIER
%token INT_LITERAL
%token STRING_LITERAL
%token PLUS PLUS_PLUS MINUS MINUS_MINUS EQUAL SEMICOLON
%%
program: block
       | /* empty */
       ;
block: '{' statement_list '}'
      ;

statement_list: statement
              | statement_list statement
              ;

statement: assignment_statement
         | increment_statement
         | decrement_statement
         ;

assignment_statement: IDENTIFIER EQUAL INT_LITERAL SEMICOLON
                   ;

increment_statement: IDENTIFIER PLUS_PLUS SEMICOLON
                  ;

decrement_statement: IDENTIFIER MINUS_MINUS SEMICOLON
                  ;

%%

int yyerror (char *s) {
fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Flex **parserlex.l code**:

```
%{
#include "parser.tab.h"
%}

%%

"{"                             { return '{'; }
"}"                             { return '}'; }
"="                             { return EQUAL; }
";"                             { return SEMICOLON; }
"++"                            { return PLUS_PLUS; }
"--"                            { return MINUS_MINUS; }
[ \t\n\r]+                      ;  // Ignore white spaces

[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*           { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER; }
[0-9]+                          { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return INT_LITERAL; }

.                               { fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized token: %s\n", yytext); return 0; }

%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong and since the only error message I get is "syntax error" I don't even know where to start looking for potential solutions.
I also tried to use bison -v and reading bison.output file but it didn't got me much. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should print out the current token as well as the message. The parser doesn’t know anything except “syntax error” so that’s all you can get out of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement better error messages for flex/bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115979/how-to-implement-better-error-messages-for-flex-bison)

Comment: @PiotrSiupa I did that and it seems to show "Error: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting INT_LITERAL" so now I'm kinda confused

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory. If you don't know which part of input it is, you could add line numbers to the error message, or try a smaller input. You can also debug your parser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821203/how-can-i-debug-my-flex-bison-grammar

Comment: Run bison woth `-t` and put `yydebug = 1;` in main just before calling yyparse to get a trace of what the parser is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some obvious limitations of your grammar:

- Your *assignment_statement* rule only accepts `IDENTIFIER EQUAL INT_LITERAL` so anything other than a constant on the rhs (such as `a = b;` -- the second line in your input) will give a syntax error
- Your top-level *program* only accepts a single *block* so it would give a syntax error on seeing a second block (if it ever got that far).

To help tracing your program, you can enable tracing code (by using the `-t` argument to bison) and turn it on by setting `yydebug = 1` before calling `yyparse()`.  I prefer putting something like

```
if (getennv('YYDEBUG')) yydebug = 1;
```

in the beginning of main and always using `-t` (or `%define parse.trace` near the top of the .y file -- same effect).  That way it will print a trace if you set `YYDEBUG` in your environment before running your program.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you you absolute legend!